# What is wrong with this counter-example to Amann-Escher Analysis I Proposition 3.8?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Exercise 2 in Chapter 1 Section 3 of Amann-Escher's Analysis I has me prove the following proposition (just the first part as that is where my confusion lies):

The following hold for the set valued function induced from $f$:

$$A \subseteq B \subseteq X \implies f(A) \subseteq f(B)$$

My understanding of a 'set valued function' is that if we have a function $f : X \to Y$, then we can also make a function $f : \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(Y)$, which doesn't really seem to receive much more explanation than the fact that $f$ is just a function from one power set to another. So let's do exactly that then: let $A = ${$a$}, $B = ${$a, b$}, and $X =$ {$a, b, c$}. Then we have that $A \subseteq B \subseteq X$, and $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ and $B \in \mathcal{P}(X)$. Let $Y = ${$d, e$}. If $f : \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(Y)$ is defined such that $f(A) = ${$d$} and $f(B) = ${$e$}, then $f(A)$ is not a subset of $f(B)$.

Am I completely misunderstanding the problem and the concept of a set-valued function? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you are self-studying this and would be interested in working through it with someone else, please let me know. I am intending to start this book this weekend and would be glad to discuss with someone else (especially given that there are no solutions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not considering any arbitrary $f$ between the power sets, but rather the map induced by the original function $f$. In your example, your $f$ is not induced by any function between $X$ and $Y$.

This is defined as following - given $f:X\rightarrow Y$, the indiced map between the associated power sets is given by
$$f(A)=\{f(a)\in Y: a \in A\}$$
Meaning - this is the image of $f$ when restricted to the subset $A$.

Keeping this definition in mind, you can see why the suggested inclusion holds. I am not sure why this is not defined in the book (I am not familiar with it) - perhaps you missed it? Either way, this is the induced map.

Comment: That definition of the image of $A$ under $f$ is given just earlier in the text but I did not see the connection that that $f(A)$ is the same as the one in the proposition! 'Induced' is not used in the earlier definition so it was hard to tell. I will work on it again now with this in mind, thank you.